# Yii2 gridview buttons problem (possibly after pjax)

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-model

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'id' => 'CompanyGrid',
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'floatHeader'=>true,
    'floatOverflowContainer'=>true,
    'floatHeaderOptions'=>['top'=>'0'],
    'pjax'=>true,  
    'pjaxSettings' => [
        'options' => [
            'enablePushState' => false,
            'enableReplaceState' => true,
        ]
    ],
    'hover'=>true,
    'toolbar' => [
        '{export}',
        '{toggleData}'
    ], 
    'panel' => [
        'heading'=>'<h3 class="panel-title"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></i> Companies</h3>',
        'type'=>'secondary',
        'before'=>Html::button('Create Company', ['value'=>Url::to('index.php?r=Company/company/create'), 'title' => 'Create Company', 'class' => 'btn btn-success', 'id' => 'modalButton']),
        'after'=>false,
    ],
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'kartik\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'CompanyID',
        'CompanyName',

        ['class' => 'kartik\grid\ActionColumn',
            'template' => '{view} {update} {delete}',
            'buttons' => [
                'view' => function($url, $model){
                    return Html::a('<span class="fa fa-eye"></span>', ['view', 'id' => $model->CompanyID], [
                        'class' => 'activity-view-link',
                        'data-pjax'=>'w0',
                        'title' => Yii::t('yii', 'View Company: '.$model->CompanyID),
                            'data-toggle' => 'modal',
                            'data-target' => '#modal',
                    ]);                        
                },
                'update' => function($url, $model){
                    return Html::a('<span class="fa fa-edit"></span>', ['update', 'id' => $model->CompanyID], [
                        'class' => 'activity-view-link',
                        'title' => Yii::t('yii', 'Edit Company: '.$model->CompanyID),
                            'data-toggle' => 'modal',
                            'data-target' => '#modal',
                    ]); 
                },                            
                'delete' => function($url, $model){
                    return Html::a('<span class="fa fa-trash"></span>', ['delete', 'id' => $model->CompanyID], [
                        'class' => '',
                        'data' => [
                            'confirm' => 'Are you absolutely sure? This action is not reversible',
                            'method' => 'post',
                        ],
                    ]);
                }                           
            ],
        ],
    ],
]); ?>
```

---

In Controller

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    $model = Company::findOne($id);
    return $this->renderAjax('view', [
        'model' => $model,          
    ]);
}
```

---

I am new in yii2-advance-apps and i am trying to solve this problem. Already worked on this problem and cannot find any solution for this.
The problem is when I click on the gridview actions buttons, it works. However, after PJax, the button just don't work anymore.
However, if i reload the page, the button works again.
How to solve this problem. Thank you in advance.

---

Comment: you have a modal and javascript which is set in document ready I guess? You have to set your javascript in pjax:success also. `$(document).on('pjax:success', function() { //your js });`

Answer (score 0):

**`'data-pjax' => 0,`** in action buttons options and not **'w0'**